net-snmp-5.7.3 errors when I run 'make'
I am currently attempting to install net-snmp-5.7.3 on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.6
I have downloaded the net-snmp-5.7.3.tar.gz file
I have extracted it and ran "./configure"
After I run "./configure" I try to run "make" and it produces the following errors:
keytools.c:155:25: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'EVP_MD_CTX' {aka 'struct evp_md_ctx_st}
155 | ctx = malloc(sizeof(*ctx));
keytools.c:265:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup': did you mean 'EVP_MD_CTX_create'?
265 | EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
Any solutions on how to fix this?
I have tried running the same commands but with 'sudo'. I expected to get the same errors and the results were as I expected.

Please use code blocks to format sample code in your question.  Are you sure that the above is the FIRST error message you see?  When looking at compiler errors you should always pay the most attention to the first messages, since the later messages could just be cascading failures caused by the earlier errors.  This message refers to EVP_MD_CTX which is part of the OpenSSL library.  Mostly likely you either don't have the developer version of that library installed on your system, or else you have the wrong version.

@MadScientist  I can confirm that the first 'error' message I see is the one I provided. I have ran both sudo apt-get install libssl-dev and sudo apt-get install opensll and both (newest versions) are already installed on my system.

You should double-check what version of OpenSSL is needed by that package.  Note that the OpenSLL library API was completely reworked for OpenSSL 3.x but many packages still use the older OpenSSL 1.x API.  I would hope that the configure script would suss out that kind of mismatch but it all depends on how diligent the author of the software was in caring about things like that.  The OpenSSL API was unchanged for many years and people may have taken it for granted.
